# Velocity and acceleration from time and altitude

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation, derivative

I am trying to calculate and plot velocity and acceleration given data points. Initially am given 13 points for time and altitude.

```
time = [0:12];
altitude = [0,107.37,210.00,307.63,400.00,484.60,550.00,583.97,580.00,...
      549.53,570.00,699.18,850];
```

These had to then be cubic fitted, done using below code

```
newTime = linspace(0,12,100);
rcubic = polyfit(time,altitude,3);
vrcubic = polyval(rcubic,newTime);
plot(newTime,vrcubic)
```

I am unsure how to properly find velocity and acceleration however. I am currently finding velocity using

```
velocity = [vrcubic./newTime];
```

and rough acceleration using

```
acceleration = [sqrt(velocity.^2 + newTime.^2)];
```

meant to be the slope of velocity between 2 point, but I think its wrong

Is there a simpler way to calculate the velocity and acceleration, possibly with a derivative or something?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your velocity is the rate of change of displacement (in your case altitude) with respect to time. The numerical approximation is thus the discrete change in altitude divided by the discrete change in time. Your equation

```
velocity = [vrcubic./newTime];
```

doesnt' account for the *change*. I would alter it to be

```
velocity = diff(vrcubic)./diff(newTime);
```

Acceleration is then just the time derivative of that. Note that you will have to drop your first time point as diff reduces the size of the vector by one:

```
acceleration = diff(velocity)./diff(newTime(2:end));
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically use derivatives to calculate velocity and acceleration! Maybe it's not that simple/more efficient way, but it is the way I thought it is correct.

Example

```
v_geral(1)=0;

for i=1:length(x)-1

x1 = x(i);
x2 = x(i+1);
y1 = y(i);
y2 = y(i+1);
z1 = z(i);
z2 = z(i+1);

if sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2+(z2-z1)^2) == 0
    v_geral(i+1)=0;
else
    v_geral(i+1)= sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2+(z2-z1)^2)/(t(i+1) - t(i));
end

end
```

You can use the same function to calculate acceleration as well. You just need to change the input